# VueJs array replacement for v-for how to make it work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have a very simple page that contains two tabs, each tab contains a list of reports with different status.

The way I am trying to do is, I have two different data source array, one for each tab and third array that is to denote current displaying array items.

When user click on the tab, I replace the third array to either first or second array according to the tab clicked.

However, the `v-for` section is not updated, but the `v-show` section is updated. I spent quite a few hours to try to solve it, have tried `Vue.set(...)` but still not working.

Anyone knows the detailed cause of the issue and what is the best solutions for it?

Following is the code, I use `OnSenUI for Vue` and `Vue router`, this is the complete component code:

```
<template id="main-page">
  <v-ons-page>
  <v-ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Reports</div>
  </v-ons-toolbar>

  <v-ons-bar>
    <p style="text-align: right; margin-right: 20px">
      <v-ons-button @click="$ons.notification.alert('TODO: implement this.')">
        + New Report
      </v-ons-button>
    </p>
  </v-ons-bar>

  <v-ons-card v-for="report in showingReports" :key="report.requestNo">
    <div class="title">
      {{report.requestNo}}
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      Submitted Date: {{report.submittedDate}}<br>
      Status: {{report.status}}<br>
      Subject: {{report.subject}}<br>
    </div>
  </v-ons-card>

  <v-ons-card v-show="!showingReports || showingReports.length == 0">
    <div class="content">
      <p class="center">
        No records found
      </p>
    </div>
  </v-ons-card>

      <v-ons-tabbar>
        <v-ons-tab label="Open" @click="selectTab(0)" :active="selectedTab == 0"></v-ons-tab>
        <v-ons-tab label="Closed" @click="selectTab(1)" :active="selectedTab == 1"></v-ons-tab>
      </v-ons-tabbar>
   </v-ons-page>
  </template>
 <script>
  export default {
  data() {
    return {
      showingReports: [],
      openedReports: [],
      closedReports: [],
      selectedTab: 0
    }
  },

  created() {
    this.getReports();
  },

  methods: {
    getReports() {
      this.allReports = [
        {
          requestNo: "REPORT18070102",
          submittedDate: Date(),
          status: "OPENED",
          subject: "Test1"
        },
        {
          requestNo: "REPORT18070103",
          submittedDate: Date(),
          status: "OPENED",
          subject: "Test2"
        }
      ];

      this.openedReports = this.allReports.filter(report => report.status == "OPENED");
      this.closedReports = this.allReports.filter(report => report.status != "OPENED");
      this.selectTab(0);
    },

    selectTab(tab) {
      this.selectedTab = tab;
      if(tab == 0){
        this.showingReports = this.openedReports;
      }else{
        this.showingReports = this.closedReports;
      }
    },
  }
}
```

To include more details, this is a simple starting project I started by reading some tutorials. This is the main.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   components: { App },
  template: '<App/>'
})
```

This is the App.vue:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>
```

This is the index.js under router foler. ReportList is the component file, which is located under components folder:

```
import Router from 'vue-router'
import ReportList from '@/components/ReportList'

import 'onsenui/css/onsenui.css';
import 'onsenui/css/onsen-css-components.css';

import Vue from 'vue';
import VueOnsen from 'vue-onsenui';

Vue.use(Router)
Vue.use(VueOnsen)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'ReportList',
      component: ReportList
    }
  ]
})
```

The dependencies in package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "prod": "webpack-dev-server --inline --progress --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js",
    "start": "npm run prod",
    "e2e": "node test/e2e/runner.js",
    "test": "npm run unit && npm run e2e",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue src test/unit test/e2e/specs",
    "build": "node build/build.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
     "onsenui": "^2.10.4",
     "vue": "^2.5.2",
     "vue-onsenui": "^2.6.1",
     "vue-router": "^3.0.1"
  },
```

-----Removed the console log, it does not help---

---

Updated: 
I make it work through another way, render the whole list but use v-show to control whether to show it. I think the "v-for" is not very reactive compared to v-show.

```
<v-ons-card v-for="report in allReports" :key="report.requestNo" v-show="shouldShow(report)">
  <div class="title">
      {{report.requestNo}}
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Submitted Date: {{report.submittedDate}}<br>
    Status: {{report.status}}<br>
    Subject: {{report.subject}}<br>
  </div>
</v-ons-card>

shouldShow(report){
    if(this.selectedTab == 0){
      return report.status == 'OPENED';
    }else{
      return report.status != 'OPENED';
    }
  },

  selectTab(tab) {
    this.selectedTab = tab;
    var hasItem = false;
    this.allReports.forEach(r => hasItem = hasItem || this.shouldShow(r));
    this.emptyList = !hasItem;
    console.log(this.emptyList);
  }
```

Comment: I think the problem is that re-assigning the array doesn't alert Vue to update the array. Vue looks for specific [array mutation methods](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods) to update the `v-for`. It also seems like some of the methods from the next section: [replacing an array](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Mutation-Methods). 

With the being said, try something like `this.showingReports = this.openedReports.slice(0);`

I think the most sure-fire way, however, is to use Vue's computed properties. I'll add a little snippet about it in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

From [List Rendering in the Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key):

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, by default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. ...
>
> This default mode is efficient, but only suitable when your list render output does not rely on child component state or temporary DOM state (e.g. form input values).
>
> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique `key` attribute for each item. An ideal value for `key` would be the unique id of each item. This special attribute is a rough equivalent to `track-by` in 1.x, but it works like an attribute, so you need to use `v-bind` to bind it to dynamic values (using shorthand here)

Because of this, you should always add a unique `key` attribute (with `v-bind`) for every element in the list to let Vue know there was a change in state.

E.g., using the `requestNo` attribute of each list item:

```
<v-ons-card v-for="report in showingReports" :key="report.requestNo">
```

---

Update (continuing my comment above):

You might want to consider using Vue's [computed properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html). They're quite powerful and intelligently update properties when their dependencies are updated. This might also fix your current issue with the list not rendering.

For example:

HTML

```
<v-ons-card v-for="report in computedReports" :key="report.requestNo">
  <!-- ... -->
</v-ons-card>
```

JS

```
data: {
  selectedTab: 0
},
computed: {
  computedReports() {
    return this.allReports.filter(report => this.isOpenedReports ?report.status != "OPENED" : report.status == "OPENED");
  }
}
methods: {
  getReports() {
    this.allReports = [
      {
        requestNo: "REPORT18070102",
        submittedDate: Date(),
        status: "OPENED",
        subject: "Test1"
      },
      {
        requestNo: "REPORT18070103",
        submittedDate: Date(),
        status: "OPENED",
        subject: "Test2"
      }
    ];
    this.selectTab(0);
  },

  selectTab(tab) {
    this.selectedTab = tab;
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, the initial displaying is OK, but when I click the tab and click back. The v-for is disappeared, left empty page, but the v-show works find.

Comment: @Surely That's interesting, and I'm not sure if this answer is completely related to that. I might need to know more information to solve that new problem.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, I edit the question to include more sources.

Comment: I'hv just started learning Vuejs, but can you `console.log` the `openReports` and `closeReports` and check if it has data? Because i was searching same thing yesterday and it does update `v-for` on data change

Comment: if it helps i used index of loop in key attribute with string like report in ur case

Comment: @Manjunath I updated the question with screenshots, and I did try the key with index, but the output is same.

Comment: @Manjunath no a list of jslint warnings, though.

Comment: @JonathanLam, I updated my code, however the behaviour is still the same. The list did render in first page load, but when click the tabs to switch to Close then Opened again, the list does not render. I make it work in another way, which make the page render all reports first and use v-show to control whether to display the item through a "shouldShow" method.